# Can Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services connect to an LDAP server other then Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ssrs

Can MS SSRS use an LDAP server other then AD for authentication?
Is this an easy configuration or is it digging ones self into a hole?

Answer (score 1):

You could setup an external trust between the Windows domain and the other LDAP database.

You could setup SSRS to use forums authentication but it would be pretty tough to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you do have a bunch of Mac guys in your network you could use Apple Open Directory.  It will act like AD against the LDAP directory.